# XML with PHP “echo” getting error “Extra content at the end of the document”

Tags: php, xml

I have asked a question here on how to [Generate a sitemap automatically, does it need to be XML?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57689/generate-a-sitemap-automatically-does-it-need-to-be-xml/57714?noredirect=1#57714)

Here is the solution we have concluded:

```
<?php
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';
        // code to extract and echo links from the file 
echo '   </urlset>';
?>

<?PHP
  // Original PHP code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
  // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

  $url = "assets/includes/menu.inc";
  $input = @file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url");
  $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
  if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach($matches as $match) {
      // $match[2] = link address
      // $match[3] = link text 
      echo '<url><loc>' . $match[2] . '</loc></url>';
    }
  }
?>
```

However, when I tried it shows the error here: http://postimg.org/image/gh5d0k4sx/ - I tried to remove the top line "`header ("Content-Type:text/xml");`" and it worked, but can I remove that line? the whole thing is for the sake of SEO so I don't know if we can delete the top line, what I am doing wrong?

Anther question: is this file now recognized as an XML file? even that it has .php extension?

Comment: Can you visit the page with the XML content (and error) and view the source? Looking at the raw XML output will help to debug the issue.

Comment: Here mate: http://loaistudio.com/sitemap

Comment: You are closing your root element with `</urlset>`, and emit `xml` snippets after that, which makes it invalid XML. Only echo `</urlset>` when you are _completely done_. XML has one, and only one, root element, not several.

Comment: How can I do that @Wrikken

Comment: What? By just moving the `echo '   </urlset>';` to the end of the file would be the answer... There's a comment _"// code to extract and echo links from the file "_ there for a reason: _that_ is the point/placeholder to put code. Not after `echo '   </urlset>';` anymore.

Comment: @Loai: To put it in a simple way, DOM is an API that manipulates XML document structure (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model); PHP, as well as most other programming languages, support this API. FYI: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP doesn't get picked up by the browser since it's a server side language.

The [header function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) doesn't modify the body of the page. It's important to keep it in though, or the browser will not recognize the document as XML.

Try removing the closing and opening PHP tags between the two parts of the script. The whitespace inbetween them may be causing your error.

```
?>

<?PHP
```

Edit: following the comments, wait until you output your `<url>` tags before closing `urlset`

Move the line to the bottom of the PHP:

```
echo '   </urlset>';
```

It's also in the best interests of clean XML to understand how to use line breaks and double quotes to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: I just did, look how it appears now: http://loaistudio.com/sitemap it does not seem right mate

Comment: I have moved the `echo '   </urlset>';` down to the bottom just before the "?>" and after the "}"

Comment: And it worked, please take a look at the URL again, I think everything seems fine, what do you think?

Comment: The URL renders without any XML parsing errors now. Good job (:

Comment: But Sean, does that mean I can use that file sitemap.php now as an XML sitemap? so I can submit it to google and bing and it will work fine? it is recognised as XML (I am considering SEO)

Comment: @Sean I just tried to validate it: http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/?lang=en&url=http://loaistudio.com/sitemap it does not seem to be working correctly. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Loai Remove all wrong spaces and make the quotation marks are correctly.

Comment: @DainisAbols here is the final code after cleaning up: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8733429 please advice

Comment: You still have en empty space between line **4** and **6** ... go with @Jens-AndréKoch answer

Comment: What do you mean by empty spaces?

Answer (score 0):

The file will not be picked up by crawlers.
According to the sitemap spec at http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html.
The filename must be sitemap.xml.

I would suggest creating the file "sitemap.xml" with

```
file_put_contents("sitemap.xml", $xmlContent);
```

A static file is faster and you can cronjob it's re-creation.

How to create a cronjob on linux?

- on shell use `cronjob -e`
- your editor opens up
- add a new cronjob line, like: `00 22 * * * /path/to/sitemapBuilder.php`
- this means: execute your sitemap generation script, every day at 22:00

Content of `sitemapBuilder.php`:

```
<?php 
 $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
             <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

 $url = "assets/includes/menu.inc";
 $input = @file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url");

 $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";

 if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
     foreach($matches as $match) {
         // $match[2] = link address
         // $match[3] = link text
         $xml .= '<url><loc>' . $match[2] . '</loc></url>';
     }
 }
 $xml .= '</urlset>';
 file_put_contents('sitemap.xml', $xml);
 ?>
```

Write sitemap.xml to the root folder of your web project, e.g. next to index.php.

You might also use a Sitemap Validator to point to your URL and check the file for validity.
For example, http://www.validome.org/google/ might help with that.

Comment: I really don't know where to add that line to do the cronjob, please can you direct me to the right place? Are you able to show a working code?

Comment: Sure, i will add the steps to my answer.

Comment: I want to learn, so if you could show me steps please do! also we have fixed the error now. I just had to move the echo ' </urlset>'; to the end. Live preview here: http://loaistudio.com/sitemap

Comment: Do I need a corjob however? as I am inserting the URLS using a PHP include "which contains all the menu links" so If I added or changed something, it will also change it in the sitemap file

Comment: That might be a valid sitemap now, but it's not picked up, because it's name is not "sitemap.xml". Read the spec: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Comment: Any ideas? please help: here is the final code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8733429

Comment: For sitemapBuilder.php? Replace echo statements with $xml .= and add file_put_contents("sitemap.xml", $xml);

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch this line you mean:`echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">'; ?>`

Comment: example added on your request.

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch I believe your answer deserve to be the correct one. I have tried your code, but it does not make the file appear as an XML file why is that?

Comment: Use the validator to check the XML schema.